# Transfer SMS from Android to iPhone?

Tags: ios, android

I would like to not lose my SMS on my Android phone, how can I transfer them to my iPhone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following third party app that can do that.

> No need to copy your text messages manually, Mobile Transfer enables
>   you to move data between different platforms with just a few clicks.
>   The contents include the date when you received and sent them, and, of
>   course, the messages themselves.

Read more here:

http://www.android-recovery.net/transfer-android-sms-to-iphone.html

http://www.transphone.net/phone-transfer/transfer-sms-from-android-to-iphone.html

[Mobile Transfer](http://www.android-recovery.net/mobile-transfer.html)

> Mobile Transfer is a professional transfer tool designed to transfer
>   contacts, text messages, call logs, photos, audio, videos calendar and
>   apps between iPhone, Android, Nokia (Symbian) and BlackBerry in just
>   one click!

http://www.android-recovery.net/downloads/mac-mobile-transfer.dmg

Comment: I used one of them, please be aware that they do not allow transferring of proprietary apps like Whatsapp: in fact one of the companies sell a tool only for this separately unfortunately.

Comment: Those two links talk about the exact same application and I have seen it referenced in a number of other places, so the "many" doesn't seem right. Has anyone used this application? Does it work?

Comment: To answer my own question, I have now used the application and it works fine. It was very straightforward to use.